# Want to fetch byte data image from localhost Api & show it in imageview

Tags: android

In my project, there is a local server from where I need to fetch an image that is in binary data form

I have tried using base64string to image code but I was unable to fetch the image

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    //decode base64 string to image
    imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Comment: can you post the code what you have tried?

Comment: Why don't you try fetching image, directly save into file and create bitmap from file?

Comment: @UmaSankar Can you give link or code for the same??

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to fetch the image and set it to a bitmap, then set the bitmap to your ImageView. Try this:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> setImageFromUrl = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                try {

                    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(IMAGE_ENDPOINT_URL));
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
                    httpRequest.abort();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bmp;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
                if (bmp != null) {

                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                }

            }
        };
```